# how can get the result and appoint into next

Tags: sql

1 )

```
SELECT A.SSID FROM T_TABLE_1 A, T_TABLE_2 B WHERE A.SSID = B.SSID AND B.NUMBER = '123456';`
```

2)

```
delete from T_TABLE_3 where ssid='139729252';
delete from T_TABLE_4 where ssid='139729252';
```

Result of 1) is a SSID, eg: '139729252' ，how can I use the result of 1) into 2), no need to copy and paste every time? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use IN operator if you expect more than 1 record to be retrieved using your select statement. Else you can use = operator.

Ex:

`delete from T_TABLE_3 
where ssid=(SELECT A.SSID FROM T_TABLE_1 A, T_TABLE_2 B WHERE A.SSID = B.SSID AND B.NUMBER = '123456');`

or

`delete from T_TABLE_3 
where ssid IN (SELECT A.SSID FROM T_TABLE_1 A, T_TABLE_2 B WHERE A.SSID = B.SSID AND B.NUMBER = '123456');`

Answer (score 0):

delete from T_TABLE_3 where ssid in ( select a.ssid t_table_1 a, t_table_2 b where a.ssid=b.ssid and b.number='123456');

or